# Symbolic breakpoints in XCode suddenly not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

Update: if you've added symbolic breakpoints and they're not working, uh, "wait awhile". After posting this and moving on and doing something else in the project, I then had an objc_exception_throw caught at some point.

I've been adding `-[NSException raise]` and `objc_exception_throw` as symbolic breakpoints to all my projects and it's worked great, but as I was recreating a project that had gone bonkers, symbolic breakpoints stopped working.

Worth mentioning: objc_exception_throw, when added, did not auto-fill the Location. Whenever I've added it in the past, it's always put "libobjc.A.dylib" in by itself.

Running the old project with

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hi", nil];
NSLog(@"here is a[2]: %@", [a objectAtIndex:2]);
```

in the "didFinishLaunching" method, I immediately get a break at the NSLog (as I should). Running the new project with the above, I get a signal "SIGABRT" and no breakpoint. The same code, even the same project, but different XCode files.

[Solved: see top of this question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolved itself. My XCode may be corrupt or something, but if you experience the above, if possible just move on and go back to the exception throwing problem later on.

Comment: Or it may be that Apple has too aggressively parallelized Xcode, so that, in some cases, if you don't have a modern ten-core iMac, it may take Xcode many seconds or minutes to resolve your breakpoint search string.